What is the name of the (non-English language) movie which is mostly set in a school
In 2009, while traveling to the USA on British Airways I watched a non-English movie which probably is a Spanish, French or German movie. I was watching the movie with English subtitles and I could not watch it completely.
Mostly the movie is set inside a school and the majority of it occurs within a class room. I think the story runs around the male class teacher (spanish/french language teacher I guess) and the students.
In one situation a girl starts to argue with the class teacher and the teacher says something to the girl which indirectly means a prostitute. The teacher tries to explain that that word is not intentional and it has different meanings in this context, but she complaints to the principal and they dismiss him or ask him to resign the job.
I have no more clues to give. Does any one know which movie this is?

I think this needs more context. Do you have any idea what the movie was about, your current description is very vague. Die Welle could be a guess..

If you watched it with subtitles, are you maybe able to remember more exactly what the spoken langauge was, as those three you listed are quite distinct.

I haven't seen the movie, but maybe it was The Class (org.: Entre Les Murs). It is a quite recent (2008) french movie about Francois Begaudeau's experiences as a literature and french teacher in a Parisian suburb, based on a book by him (he also plays the role of the teacher himself).
